# How to run an application from host on guest OS in virtualbox?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, virtualization

I am wondering how to run an application from the host OS on a guest OS? I know this is possible but am unsure how to do it. The Host is windows 7 and the guest is Windows XP.  Is it possible without me manually installing the application on the guest?

Also would could it be possible to run an application from the host on the guest if the host was Windows 7 and the guest was Ubuntu without it appearing on the host machine? I know this is possible with rdp using Windows server but I am looking at windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

If the application doesn't need any fancy registry settings/etc. to run you could probably share the application directory from the host disk to the guest and then run it from there but that will only work if the application can support being run without being "installed".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this kind of seamless running is logistically impossible. Because apps are basically given free reign over the computer when run Windows (or Virtualbox, for that matter) has NO idea where the application will write or make changes. In effect, you'd be copying the entire OS, just to be sure that nothing is dropped or lost! If you want to simulate XP conditions on W7, I'd suggest [compatibility mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-compatibility-mode/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without installing the application in your second environment. Even in the Remote Apps / RDP example you cite, the apps are actually installed on the server and RDP is pulling a lot of visual strings to make it seem like the app is running locally. Its all visual masquerades. The apps are installed remotely and execute remotely.

Running Virtual Box in seamless mode is probably the closest you can get. It tries to hide the fact that some of the apps you have open are running on the VM while others are running natively. You still need to install the apps in the virtual machine.

Specifically with regards to running Ubuntu applications in Windows, you may find the SSH + X11 forwarding does what you want. It is nearly exactly the same thing as Microsoft remote apps. You may also find that Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) provides an equivalently nice experience.